# How to get roxygenise() to check for duplicate function definitions

Tags: r, package

I am compiling a package using `roxygen2`. I would like to be able to make sure that there no function is defined twice with the same name. However, currently `roxygenise()` builds the package without issuing a warning.

E.g.

```
library(roxygen2)

#' Real function
real_function <- function(){print("hello world")}

#' Fake function
real_function <- function(){}
```

Calling `roxygenise()` leads to the second definition being used.

Comment: When you assign the second  `real_function`, you're overwriting the previous assignment anyway. So, I'd say that `roxygenise` behaves as expected. What are you trying to do? You can't have multiple functions of the same name in R.  So you can't do function overloading if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: I would like a warning, with line numbers and file names containing the duplicate functions. While it is not normal to have two functions with the same name in one source file, it is quite possible to have duplicates across multiple source files, especially if you are collating code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think `roxygenise` can or should do this. If you want to check yourself for duplicate names, you can e.g. run through the files in a directory and attach each file sequentially. The `attach` function has a `warn.conflicts` argument that is `TRUE` by default.

```
check_duplicate_names <- function(dir){
  files <- list.files(dir)
  for (file in file.path(dir, files)){
    duplicate_test_env <- new.env()
    sys.source(file, envir = duplicate_test_env)
    attach(duplicate_test_env)
  }
  for (i in seq_along(files)){
    detach(duplicate_test_env)
  }
}
check_duplicate_names("path-to-package/R")
```

Note that if you have duplicate functions within one file this will not work.